# Get selected value of dynamically created multiple dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to ask 2 questions.

1. I have created dynamic dropdown (class and section) using jquery and
   assign the id's like `[myclass0, myclass1]` `[mysection0, mysection1]`
   etc. Now I want to retrieve the values of both and store in a
   variable or array then I will use these variable for sending it to
   database. I have done the following code but it's not working and
   even it's not showing the ID of dynamic created dropdown.
2. How to select the values of classes and sections and how to loop them so that valid data will be sent to database?

here is my code

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="dynamic_select">     
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="" value="Add Class" class="btn btn-primary" id="addclass" style="margin-top: 50px;" onclick="addMore();">
```

here is my JS:

```
function addMore(){
          var inps = $('#dynamic_select > div:last').data('count')+1 || 0;
          $('#dynamic_select').append('<div data-count="'+inps+'"><div class = "col-sm-5"><label>Select Class</label> <select id="childclass'+inps+' "  class="form-control"> <option value="9">IX</option><option value="10">X</option><option value="11">FSC I</option><option value="12">FSC II</option></select> </div>    <div class = "col-sm-5"><label>Select Section</label> <select id="childsection'+inps+' "  class="form-control"> <option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="C">C</option></select></div> <a class=remove>X</a>');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (example for #dynamic_select):

```
$('#dynamic_select select').val();
```

**or**

```
$('#dynamic_select).on('change', function() {
   $('#dynamic_select select').val();
});
```

Comment: It is working only if you add one class but Let's say I have created 3 dynamic dropdown, Now how can I store classes and sections on different variables.